# Autocomplete and modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, autocomplete

I have a modal div and textbox inside this div. I want to set an autocomplete for the textbox. To set z-index correctly for autocomplete I use the following code:

```
$('.autocompleteTextbox')
    .autocomplete("option", "appendTo", "#my_dialog");
```

it works fine, but I want to set it for many modal divs and these divs are generated automatically

So, I try this code:

```
var ac = $('.autocompleteTextbox');
$('.modal').each(function(i,v) {
    var id = v.id;
    ac.autocomplete("option", "appendTo", id);
});
```

it does not work

```
$('.modal').each(function(i,v) {
    var id = v.id;
    ac.autocomplete("option", "appendTo", v);
});
```

it does not work too. How to do it correctly?

Comment: I think it should be `ac.autocomplete('option', 'appendTo', '#' + id);`

Comment: does not work at all. Even under modal :)

Comment: if you copied that directly, I had a spelling error in there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution

```
    $('.modal').each(function(i,v)
    {
        $(this).find('.autocompleteTextbox').autocomplete("option", "appendTo", v);
    });
```

or

```
    $('.modal').each(function(i,v)
    {
        $(this).find('.autocompleteTextbox').autocomplete("option", "appendTo", this);
    });
```

or

```
$('.modal').each(function(i,v)
{
    $(this).find('.autocompleteTextbox').autocomplete("option", "appendTo", '#' + this.id);
});
```

Comment: or `$(v).find('.autocompleteTextbox').autocomplete({appendTo:v});` to get it as short as possible :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.modal').each(function () {
    $(this).find('.autocompleteTextbox').autocomplete("option", "appendTo", '#' + this.id);
});
```

Another option is to add class `ui-front` to `.modal` div. In this case you don't need to specify [`appendTo`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-appendTo) option because

> If an element with the ui-front class is found, the menu will be appended to that element.

Comment: Can you post your HTML structure?

Comment: I think that the `v.id` is a problem :)

Comment: found the solution, you was very closer. Should be .autocomplete("option", "appendTo", v); not autocomplete("option", "appendTo", v.id); . Thank you!

Comment: @ArturFilipiak Thank you it should be `this.id` of course.

Comment: @ArturFilipiak no, v.id will return an id.

Comment: @OlegSh Yes, if you pass `v` argument it's `v.id`, the same as `this.id`.

Comment: @Chad Good one, then it should be `# + this.id` :) In this case using of `v` is even better.

Comment: 'this.id' does not work too :) should be $(this).find('.autocompleteTextbox').autocomplete("option", "appendTo", v); or $(this).find('.autocompleteTextbox').autocomplete("option", "appendTo", this);

Comment: @OlegSh Yes, with id it should be `# + this.id` to be a correct CSS selector. In this case simple `v` looks nicer.

Comment: Typically I avoid using this in functions like that.

Comment: When you get into plugin development, `this` is used for the plugin itself, so you end up with contextual functions. So take my basic plugin model, and look at the consoles: http://jsfiddle.net/Lf9soczg/

Comment: @Chad Not sure what you are trying to explain me. Of course if one uses `this` then it's important to understand how to use it and what context it is used in. In my example I know what `this` is and the problem can't occur.

Comment: @dfsq basically the `v` is the absolute context, while `this` changes sometimes. I'm not saying you have to avoid using this, just that it's a preference for when the JS gets more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

your change the z-index of div od the result of the autocomplete:

If is jquery.ui add in a style tag:

```
<style>
.ui-autocomplete { 
           position: absolute;
           cursor: default;
           z-index:999 !important;
}  
</style>
```